# How to set free shipping once the amount is reached for free shipping

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Hi i have set two zones in my website and have allocated different shipping price according to postal codes. for east zone i have allocated free shipping $300 or above  and for west zone $200 and above. for east zone it is working fine it automatically shows up free shipping and local pickup when customer reaches 300$ but for west zone if customer reaches $200 it shows Standard shipping, free shipping and local pickup.

any help that how can i remove standard shipping if west customer reaches to 200$?

Comment: You said that you have segregated the zone based on zip code, so during checkout you are writing the west zip code? and please also share the screenshot of your shipping configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I have configured the shipping condition based on the condition you needed you can cross check.

1. Add shipping Zone in your case East zone for testing I only added Florida. [Not able to add image, so provided the link]

[Add shipping zone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBheJ.png)

2. Under shipping zone, add free shipping for a minimum price.

[Free shipping condition for east zone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxmrO.png)

3. Similarly, add west shipping zone.

Now you can check the cart page under the different condition:-

condition 1: Cart value > 200 
[Free shipping for orders over 200](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYIyk.png)

Condition 2: Cart vale < 200
[Stadard shipping for orders under 200](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNzND.png)

Condition 3: Cart value 200-300
[Stadard shipping for order value 200-300](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFQVt.png)

If you have followed the similar steps that I followed then I guess you should not face any issue.

By configuring within WooCommerce shipping zone you can add these basic conditions. But this method is not good for more complicated method. For more complicated condition you can use [WooCommerce Table Rate Shipping Pro Plugin](https://www.pluginhive.com/product/woocommerce-table-rate-shipping-pro-plugin/). You can easily configure for the above condition using this plugin:

You can add the shipping zone and in the shipping pro within WooCommerce shipping settings add conditions based on your condition.

Here is the shipping rule based on your condition:
[Shipping rules under shipping pro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eU6SS.png)

Now you can check the shipping rules on different conditions:

[Shipping methods under different cart value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4XRa.png)
 I hope this answered your question.